# Can't see folder in windows explorer and can't rename

Tags: python, scripting, automation, windows-10

I'm new to programming, python, and StakeOverflow in general ( I had one programming course in college and one in high school). I made this script to cleanout out my downloads folder but I am running into some issues. The folder I create is not visible in windows explorer and I can't seem to rename the I created folder. I'm running windows 10 if that makes any difference.

```
import os
import time
import shutil


# Create a folder to store the downloads in
def makefolder():
    os.chdir(os.chdir('C:\\')
    os.makedirs('C:\Users\keega\Documents\A')

# Moves the files
def movefiles():
    os.chdir('C:\Users\keega\Documents\Downloads')
    shutil.copytree('C:\Users\keega\Documents\Downloads','C:\Users\keega\Documents\A')


# Rename the folder just created
def renamefolder():
    os.chdir('C:\Users\keega\Documents')
    nameoffolder= 'Downloads' + str((time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")))
    os.rename('A',nameoffolder)
    Return

#delete the old files
def deletedownloads():
    os.chdir('C:\Users\keega\Downloads')
    shutil.rmtree('C:\Users\keega\Downloads')


makefolder()
movefiles()
renamefolder()
deletedownloads()
```

Comment: What exactly is this supposed to do? `os.chdir(os.chdir('C:\\')`

Comment: That's a typo from when I copied the code over. I was trying to figure out what chdir did but I had commented it out. For some reason I uncommented it.

Comment: As an aside, always use raw strings `r'C:\Users\keega\Documents\A'` or escape backslashes `'C:\\Users\\keega\\Documents\\A'` to avoid confusion with string escapes such as `\t` (tab) and `\U` (on python3, unicode).

Answer (score 0):

Change the capitalized C: to c:\ , and delete the folder A since it will be created again other wise it will run an error.

```
import os
import time
import shutil


# Create a folder to store the downloads in
def makefolder():
    os.mkdir('c:\\Users\\keega\\Documents\\A')

# Moves the files
def movefiles():
    os.chdir('c:\\Users\\keega\\Documents\\Downloads')
    shutil.copytree('c:\\Users\\keega\\Documents\\Downloads','c:\\Users\\keega\\Documents\\A')


# Rename the folder just created
def renamefolder():
    os.chdir('c:\\Users\\keega\\Documents')
    nameoffolder= 'Downloads' + str((time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")))
    os.rename('A',nameoffolder)
    Return

#delete the old files
def deletedownloads():
    os.chdir('c:\\Users\\keega\\Downloads')
    shutil.rmtree('c:\\Users\\keega\\Downloads')


makefolder()
movefiles()
renamefolder()
deletedownloads()
```

Comment: Now I can't see the folder I made in the cmd and the error message says I file already exist. How do I delete the folder?

Comment: navigate from your computer to c:\Users\keega\Documents\A , you should be able to see the folder A.

Comment: That's the issue I can find the folder in the CMD but not in windows explorer. I have hidden files on but I'm not sure what to do.